# What are some good, cheap hosts that supports Django?

Tags: web-hosting, personal-website, django

I'm doing a personal web site in Django. It'll be fairly light, and I don't expect many visitors, so I don't need 500gb of bandwidth or 10gb of hard drive which most hosting servers seem to provide as their minimum.

The web site itself should be less than 10mb in size (plus Python/Django installation) and if I reach 100 visitors per month I'll be lucky. ;) It'll be a place for me to keep my portfolio. While bandwidth and space isn't something I need much of, I still need to be relatively stable and fast (I'd hate to send my portfolio to a recruiter only to have it be down due to maintanence or whatever).

Comment: This is a 'list of' question, I have made it community wiki.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/) is our preferred Django hosting solution. There is a [solid helper library](http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-django/) to deal with any inconsistencies. You get lots of hosting bandwidth/resources for free and if you set your daily billable amount to $0.00 (technically the same as free but they now have your credit card details) you get around 50% more resources. The upcoming Business App Engine should offer own domain SSL.

Comment: Oh, thanks. That definitely seems to be what I'm looking for, if I'm reading it right. Thanks. :)

Comment: What version of Django is App Engine supporting?

Comment: I think that are still only support Django 0.96.1. :(  http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html

Comment: You can download a zip of Django and using the helper we've had the latest version working fine.

Comment: We also haven't noticed a difference in speed (even down to the reported CPU ms live) when using a zip (versus extracting locally).   However we do set `derived_file_type: - python_precompiled` in `app.yaml` which may skew the results.

Comment: Note that the Google App Engine uses the Google data store instead of the traditional relational databases the Django is designed for.

Answer (score 5):

I have a Webfaction account and I love it! Setting up an Django application in it is a breeze, its very simple and just works. The forums and the community is great too.

Comment: I looked at Webfaction but they are really providing (and charging for) stuff I don't really need.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using DreamHost for a few months now, and getting things started with them was pretty straightforward. They have an easy script that will allow Django processes to be managed by Passenger. It also gives you an easy route to try out Rails-based or PHP-based applications if you decide later on.3

Check out [Dreamhost's Wiki on Django](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Django).

Answer (score 0):

Give [Stackable](http://stackable.com) a try.  We've worked hard to build robust Django hosting and the hosting is laterally & vertically scalable.  Full disclosure - I own the company.

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing a lot of django exploration lately with PythonAnywhere, which has a reasonable "free" level and would probably meet the criteria original posted just fine (I'm going to assume that 8 years later, the original poster has long since resolved the question for himself.)

Among the potentially positive reasons to consider PythonAnywhere is the fact that the author of "Test-Driven Development with Python" works there, so there are nice resources to learn, beyond hosting a simple site.